# How can I nest a div with a image using JQuery and html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I have a for loop that displays description boxes on a map in a certain location. I what to add a pin image to the box that point directly to the location on the map.

How do I add a new div to the current div that contains an image and be able to move the image around the description box. I know I need to add the code to this for loop but I'm having a issue with how to add it.

I appreciate all the help in advance.

```
    for(var x=0; x<itemIDs.length; x++) {
            console.log("x: " + x);
            $('<div class="'+itemClass1s[x]+' hidden" id="hidden'+itemIDs[x]+'" style="left:'+itemXs[x]+'px; top:'+itemYs[x]+'px;">'+itemContents[x]+'</div>').appendTo($('#hiddenItems'));
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For as far as I know, to drag things around you will need to use JavaScript and/or jQuery. Check out this link on [jQuery Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on this. I want to be able to place the image of a pin at the corner of the description box that the for loop creates when I press a button. Right now the for loop displays boxes without the pin image attached to it. I want to place a pin image on the corner of the box that displays.I guess I want to wrap to divs together to create one image basically. I hope that's understandable.

Comment: I've been searching to try and find what I kind of need and this topic is the closes thing I can find to what I need is this topic: "How to add image and div using jquery in a dynamically added wrapped div?" The solution has an image next to a close link. I want to do something like that but have an image next to a display box.